# How do I empty the contents of a galleria gallery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, galleria

I have an array of elements which I am 'push'ing to a galleria object for dynamic content.

I need to empty the galleria first, though - effectively re-using the same galleria object.

```
Galleria.get(0).splice(0,-1);
for(var i=0;i<dat.length;++i){
     tempDat=eval('('+dat[i]+')');
     Galleria.get(0).push(tempDat);
}
Galleria.get(0).splice(0,1);
```

This seemed to have been working, but now does not. Is there any better option for me?

Also, when it *was* working, this double splice thing would not reset the active image - I'd have to go "forward" then "backward" to load the new "first" image.

I hope this all makes sense.

Thanks,